# Prism Navigation With Default Registered View

Tags: wpf, navigation, prism

Ok, so i have come across an interesting situation where the answer is eluding me. I have a User Control, in side of which has a PRISM region attached to a control. I want to set an initial view to that region, so inside the Module, i do something like 
`_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(StaticRegionNames.RegionName, typeof(firstView))`

when I run the program, it shows just fine, as I would expect it to. Now, on a button click, i navigate that region to another view, using

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(
        regionName: StaticRegionNames.RegionName,
        source: new Uri(viewNameToNavigateTo, UriKind.Relative))
```

And this works as well. The issue comes when I want to go back to the initial view (firstView).

I am trying something like:

```
var region = _regionManager.Region[StaticRegionNames.RegionName];
if(region.NavigationService.Journal.CanGoBack)
    retgion.NavigationService.Journal.GoBack();
```

This call right above doesn't work for the context of "I just navigated from the default view to the next view", but if I navigate that region again to yet another view, I am able to go back to the second view with this call.

After debugging, I am truly stumped, because the region shows that it has 2 view in it, but the value for `CanGoBack` is false.

I tried View Injection, but that doesn't work because the module loads before the region is visible, so there is no region in the RegionManager with that name yet. I tried creating one, but that then doesn't seem to register with the UserControl's region.

I also tried the lambda version of the RegisterViewWithRegion, but the outcome is exactly the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of PRISM are you using?

Comment: Should we assume that `retgion` in your second code snippet is a typo in the question, and not really in the code?

Comment: This should work. What is the difference between the first and second navigation? Are you sure that you are using the same instance of the RegionManager? Please always provide a repo when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look on [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=pandp.40).aspx) in the PRISM 5 guide, you can find a note about this (emphasis mine):

> The navigation journal can only be used for region-based navigation
>   operations that are coordinated by the region navigation service. If
>   you use **view discovery** or **view injection** to implement navigation
>   within a region, the navigation journal will not be updated during
>   navigation and cannot be used to navigate forward or backward within
>   that region.

So the only possible way to do that is to navigate to the default view using the `Region`'s `NavigationService`.

Comment: Thank you much! I found this answer a few days ago, but forgot to update my question. Thanks again!!!